# Eclipse Errors on OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I have been a Windows user for many years but the other day, I made the switch to Mac. I use Eclipse on Windows to do my Java projects for University, and having imported these into Eclipse on OSX Leopard, I get all sorts of errors, on programs that worked fine before. Any suggestions, as I am new to the Mac platform and have no idea where to start. Pic below for reference.
Here is a screenshot of my errors: [Eclipse Errors](http://cl.ly/a651df9adddd258bb3e7)

Comment: I see all the errors have to do with Queue objects. What does Eclipse tell you when you mouse over the errors?

Comment: All errors "Cannot be resolved to a type"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though Eclipse isn't able to find some of your referenced classes, including those that should ship with the JDK such as java.util.Queue. I suspect that, if you just imported an external project, the issue is that your project's JDK is configured to your old machine's path. Go into your project settings and look for the registered JDK - you'll probably see an error that it doesn't exist in the current location - switch it over to your system default and that ought to clear up the errors in your screenshot.

Comment: Thanks :) I updated Eclipse to use the 1.6 JRE and all is now well.